# Terse, warning-free, generic list declaration?

Tags: java, list, generics, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

What's the **tersest** way to declare a list/array literal in Java, both at point of declaration and point of use?

As a secondary concern, I'd prefer a method that doesn't cause a compile-time  warnings or require warnings to be suppressed.

Note: Personally this is for [Java 8ish on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html), incase that changes the answers.

I've tried:

```java
    // error: generic array creation
    Pair<Integer, String>[] data4 = new Pair<Integer, String>[] {
            new Pair<Integer, String>(0, "00000000"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "00000001"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(127, "11111111"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(128, "10000000")
    };
```

```java
    // warning: unchecked assignment
    Pair<Integer, String>[] data4 = new Pair[] {
            new Pair<Integer, String>(0, "00000000"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "00000001"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(127, "11111111"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(128, "10000000")
    };
    for (Pair<Integer, String> x : data4) {
    }
```

```java
    Pair[] data5 = new Pair[] {
            new Pair<Integer, String>(0, "00000000"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "00000001"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(127, "11111111"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(128, "10000000")
    };
    // warning: unchecked assignment
    for (Pair<Integer, String> x : data5) {
    }
    for (Pair x : data5) {
        //warning: unchecked assignment
        Pair<Integer, String> y = x;
    }
```

```java
    // warning: unchecked generics array creation for vargs parameter
    List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = Arrays.asList(
            new Pair<Integer, String>(0, "00000000"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "00000001"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(127, "11111111"),
            new Pair<Integer, String>(128, "10000000")
    );
    for (Pair<Integer, String> x : data) {
    }
```

```java
    List<Pair> data2 = Arrays.asList(
            (Pair) new Pair<Integer, String>(0, "00000000"),
            (Pair) new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "00000001"),
            (Pair) new Pair<Integer, String>(127, "11111111"),
            (Pair) new Pair<Integer, String>(128, "10000000")
    );
    // warning: unchecked assignment
    for (Pair<Integer, String> x : data2) {
    }
    for (Pair x : data2) {
        // warning: unchecked assignment
        Pair<Integer, String> y = x;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any warnings when using the 4th `List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = Arrays.asList` sample (jdk1.8.0_91).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight away, discount any of the choices which use [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Then discount the ones which mix generics and arrays.

That basically leaves

```
List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = Arrays.asList(...);
```

There are a few ways to avoid the warning here:

- Suppress it. (e.g. `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`)
- Don't try to add the elements immediately:

  ```
  List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
  data.add(new Pair<>(1, ""));
  // ...
  ```
- Use something like Guava's [`ImmutableList.of`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E...-) (works without generic arrays only up to 11 parameters):

  ```
  List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = ImmutableList.of(
      new Pair<>(1, ""),
      // ...
      );
  ```
- Create an "adder" class, something like:

  ```
  class ListAdder<T, L extends List<T>> {
    L list;

    ListAdder(L list) { this.list = list; }

    L list() { return list; }

    ListAdder<T> add(T item) { list.add(item); return this; }
  }
  ```

  and use it like:

  ```
  List<Pair<Integer, String>> list =
      new ListAdder<>(new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>())
          .add(new Pair<>(1, ""))
          // ...
          .list();
  ```
- If you *must*, you can use double-brace initialization - but you must be aware of the problems with it (like it being prone to memory leaks, it creates an extra class, etc etc):

  ```
  List<Pair<Integer, String>> data = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, String>>() {{
    add(new Pair<>(1, ""));
    // ...
  }};
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Even before posting the question I'd just settled on `Arrays.asList` and suppressing the warnings. I didn't like doing that and wanted a "better" solution, but it doesn't look like there is. Everything else is too spammy! It was in testing code so I didn't care much. In real code I might just go for the `.add ` variety.